# Animating backgroundColor in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

How would I go about animating from one color to another in React Native. I've found that by interpolating an Animated.Value you can animate colors by:

```js
var BLACK = 0;
var RED = 1;
var BLUE = 2;

backgroundColor: this.state.color.interpolate({
  inputRange: [BLACK, RED, BLUE],
  outputRange: ['rgb(0, 0, 0)', 'rgb(255, 0, 0)', 'rgb(0, 0, 255)']
})
```

and

```js
Animated.timing(this.state.color, {toValue: RED}).start();
```

But using this method, going from BLACK to BLUE, you have to go through red. Add more colors to the mix and you end up in a 1980s disco.

Is there another way of doing this that allows you to go straight from one color to another?

Comment: In your example your use inputRange: [BLACK, RED, BLUE]. If you change this to [BLACK, BLUE] does the color animate from black to blue the way you would expect?

Comment: That would work, but is the opposite of what I need. I need to add colors to the list and transition from one to the other depending on user action. So from BLACK to BLUE, then from BLUE to GREEN, then from GREEN to yellow, for example.

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I'm also struggling with the same stuff right now. It's really weird because it looks like it's a real problem for RN

Answer (score 86):

Given you have `Animated.Value` lets say `x`, you can interpolate color like this:

```js
render() {
    var color = this.state.x.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 300],
        outputRange: ['rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)', 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 1)']
    });

    return (
        <Animated.View style={{backgroundColor:color}}></Animated.View>
    );
}
```

You can find full working example in the issue I've posted on [github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4386).

Comment: Newest react-native version may have a bug - trying this code to interpolate from white to blue and getting a "received bad props" error with 'rgba(255,255,255,1)' where it's expecting 'rgba(255,255,255,1.0)'. Investigating.

Comment: Ah, I was trying to add animation on top of the above code example and forgot to use Animated.View instead of the regular View. Switching to <Animated.View> fixed my problem.

Comment: I get `Style property 'backgroundColor' is not supported by native animated module`

Comment: @onmyway133 do you use native driver ? If yes turn it to false

Comment: Can I use with LottieView animation?

Comment: Is it just me or does this answer not help OP solve the problem of going from color A to color C without passing through color B? All this does is interpolate from red to green. It doesn't show how you can with on interpolation range transition directly between colors regardless of the order in which they are placed in the interpolation's output range.

Comment: As @ebillis mentioned, remove the native driver property if your using it.

Answer (score 12):

If you could get the color of the animated color value at the instant you pressed the button then you could probably do it.  Something like this :

```js
var currentColor = ? : 
this.state.color = 0; 
var bgColor = this.state.color.interpolate({
  inputRange: [0, 1],
  outputRange: [currentColor, targetColor]
});
```

So for each button you'd set a different targetColor.

Answer (score 1):

I created an example here that should how to do this with the lastest version of react native.

https://cjoshmartin.com/blog/react-native-animations-example/

you can also read more here:
https://www.codedaily.io/courses/Master-React-Native-Animations/Color-Background-Color
https://reactnative.dev/docs/animations

Answer (score 1):

I did a hook to do what David Schumann told.

useColorAnimation.js

```
import { useRef, DependencyList, useMemo, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Animated } from "react-native";

const useColorAnimation = (color) => {
  const anim = useMemo(() => new Animated.Value(0), [color]);
  const [finished, setFinished] = useState(true)
  const currentColor = useRef(color);
  const nextColor = useMemo(()=> color, [color]);

  const animColor = anim.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [currentColor.current, nextColor],
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    setFinished(false)
    Animated.spring(anim, {
      toValue: 1,
      useNativeDriver: false,
    }).start(() => {
      currentColor.current = nextColor;
      setFinished(true)
    });

  }, [color]);

  return [animColor, finished];
};

export default useColorAnimation
```

using the hook:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Animated, Button } from 'react-native';
import useColorAnimation from './useColorAnimation';

const colors = ['rgb(0, 0, 0)', 'rgb(255, 0, 0)', 'rgb(0, 0, 255)'];

const getNextColor = (currentColor) => {
  const index = colors.indexOf(currentColor) + 1;
  return index == colors.length ? colors[0] : colors[index];
};

export default function App() {
  const [color, setColor] = useState(colors[0]);
  const [backgroundColor, finished] = useColorAnimation(color);
  const handleButton = () => setColor((current) => getNextColor(current));

  return (
    <Animated.View style={[styles.container, { backgroundColor }]}>
      <Button title="Next" onPress={handleButton} disabled={!finished} />
    </Animated.View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    flex: 1,
  },
});
```

here an example https://snack.expo.dev/@rafaelnsantos/rude-croissant

Answer (score 0):

Managed to stop mine from blinking when in a loop by duplicating the first colour at the end:

```
  const backgroundColourIndex = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;

  let backgroundColorAnimated = backgroundColourIndex.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1, 2, 3],
    outputRange: ['red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'red'],
  });
```

Answer (score -3):

You can also interpolate in steps, for non-numeric values like color, like this:

```js
<Animated.Text
  style={{
    color: colorAnim.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 0.5, 1],
      outputRange: ['black', 'gray', 'white']
  })
}}>
```

Answer (score -3):

```
const animatedBkg = interpolate(scale, {
  inputRange: [0, 150],
  outputRange: [Animated.color(242, 81, 48), Animated.color(0,0,0)],
  // extrapolate: Extrapolate.CLAMP,
})
```

tested with reanimated.

Comment: What is Animated.Color?

Answer (score -22):

Use `setValue` and state to control start and end colors.