# React Native - Button Styling Trouble

Tags: react-native

I have a questions regarding React Native:

Can i transition background colour like I would do using CSS :active selector and transition?

If not, what would be the best alternative to achieve at least similar design?

Comment: You can use Animation, see answers in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32622466/animating-backgroundcolor-in-react-native

Comment: Thank you!
I will check it out :)

Answer (score 0):

You may do so by using the `onPressIn` and `onPressOut` callbacks on the `TouchableHighlight` and `TouchableWithoutFeedback` together with the `Animation` API to create such an animation. React Native also provides this behavior for `TouchableHighlight`, you may set an underlay color, which comes up as soon as it is clicked.