# Animate Gradient Color React Native

Tags: javascript, animation, react-native, reactjs

I'm trying to create a gradient in react native that will start as one color when the app opens, and then gradually change into another color every 30 seconds. The regular linear gradient worked without trying to add animation. I tried using interpolation and the Animated timing as seen in the react native documentation, but nothing seems to work.

My Code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {processColor, AppRegistry, StyleSheet, Dimensions, Animated, Image, Easing, View} from 'react-native';

import TimerMixin from 'react-timer-mixin';
import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient';

var screenWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
var screenHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;

//HEX version of colors
var gradientColors = [['#EF2A2A', '#EF6A2A'], //Red
['#EF6A2A', '#EFD82A'], //Orange
['#1BD170', '#61E822'], //Green
['#22D2E6', '#26F084'], //Aqua
['#2A3BEF', '#2ADCEF'], //Blue
['#EF2AD2', '#2A3BEF'], //Purple
['#EF2AD2', '#EF2A2A'] //Pink
]
var gradientColorsNoHash = [['EF2A2A', 'EF6A2A'], //Red
['EF6A2A', 'EFD82A'], //Orange
['1BD170', '61E822'], //Green
['22D2E6', '26F084'], //Aqua
['2A3BEF', '2ADCEF'], //Blue
['EF2AD2', '2A3BEF'], //Purple
['EF2AD2', 'EF2A2A'] //Pink
]
/*var gradientColors = [['ef2a2a', 'ef6a2a'], //Red
['ef6a2a', 'efd82a'], //Orange
['1bd170', '61e822'], //Green
['22d2e6', '26f084'], //Aqua
['2a3bef', '2adcef'], //Blue
['ef2ad2', '2a3bef'], //Purple
['ef2ad2', 'ef2a2a'] //Pink
]*/
//RGBA Version of Colors
/*var gradientColors = [['rgba(239, 42, 42, 1)', 'rgba(239, 106, 42, 1)'], //Red
['rgba(239, 106, 42, 1)', 'rgba(239, 216, 42, 1)'], //Orange
['rgba(0, 221, 103, 1)', 'rgba(97, 232, 35, 1)'], //Green
['rgba(34, 210, 230, 1)', 'rgba(38, 240, 132, 1)'], //Aqua
['rgba(42, 59, 239, 1)', 'rgba(42, 220, 239, 1)'], //Blue
['rgba(239, 42, 210, 1)', 'rgba(42, 59, 239, 1)'], //Purple
['rgba(239, 42, 210, 1)', 'rgba(239, 42, 42, 1)'] //Pink
]*/

function hex(c) {
  var s = "0123456789abcdef";
  var i = parseInt(c);
  if (i == 0 || isNaN(c))
    return "00";
  i = Math.round(Math.min (Math.max (0, i), 255));
  //console.log('hex(c) complete!');
  return s.charAt((i - i % 16) / 16) + s.charAt(i % 16);
}

// Convert an RGB triplet to a hex string
function convertToHex (rgb) {
  return hex(rgb[0]) + hex(rgb[1]) + hex(rgb[2]);
}

// Convert a hex string to an RGB triplet
function convertToRGB(hex) {
  var color = [];
  color[0] = parseInt(hex.substring(0, 2), 16);
  color[1] = parseInt(hex.substring(2, 4), 16);
  color[2] = parseInt(hex.substring(4, 6), 16);
  return color;
}

function generateColor(colorStart,colorEnd,colorCount) {

    // The beginning of your gradient
    var start = convertToRGB(colorStart);

    // The end of your gradient
    var end   = convertToRGB(colorEnd);

    // The number of colors to compute
    var len = colorCount;

    //Alpha blending amount
    var alpha = 0.0;

    var saida = [];

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        var c = [];
        alpha += (1.0/len);

        c[0] = start[0] * alpha + (1 - alpha) * end[0];
        c[1] = start[1] * alpha + (1 - alpha) * end[1];
        c[2] = start[2] * alpha + (1 - alpha) * end[2];

        saida.push(convertToHex(c));

    }

    return saida;

}

var number = randomIntFromInterval(0,6)
function randomIntFromInterval(min,max) { return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min); }

const GradientView = React.createClass({
  mixins: [TimerMixin],

  getInitialState() {
    return {
      gradIndex: number,
      colorTop: gradientColors[number][0],
      colorBottom: gradientColors[number][1],
    }
  },
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setInterval(() => {

      var count = 0
      var topGradArray = generateColor(gradientColorsNoHash[this.state.gradIndex][0],(this.state.gradIndex === 6 ? 0 : gradientColorsNoHash[this.state.gradIndex+1][0] ),770);
      var bottomGradArray = generateColor(gradientColorsNoHash[this.state.gradIndex][1],(this.state.gradIndex === 6 ? 0 : gradientColorsNoHash[this.state.gradIndex+1][1] ),770);
      console.log('Gradients Made');
      var clearId = this.setInterval(() => {
        if (count == 0) {
          this.setState({ clearId: clearId, gradIndex: ( this.state.gradIndex === 6 ? 0 : this.state.gradIndex+1 ) });
          console.log('clearId SET!');
            }

            this.setState({
              colorTop: processColor(topGradArray[count]),
              colorBottom: processColor(bottomGradArray[count]),
            });
            count = count+1

            if (count == 769) {
              console.log('colorTop and Bottom Saved');
              this.clearInterval(this.state.clearId)
            }
          }, 13);

    }, 30000);
  },

  render(){
    return(
      <LinearGradient colors={[this.state.colorTop, this.state.colorBottom]}>
        <View style={styles.translucentContainer}/>
      </LinearGradient>
    );
  }
});

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  translucentContainer: {
    width: screenWidth,
    height: screenHeight,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    opacity: 0.3,
  },
});

export default GradientView;
AppRegistry.registerComponent('GradientView', () => GradientView);
```

UPDATE: After going through many different resources, I've come to the conclusion that the only way to animate the LinearGradient class is to change the color incrementally and rapidly like in their documentation. However, their example is continuous and doesn't allow you to set a desired final color. For my application, I want the gradient to stay one color for 30 seconds, and then go through a 10 second transition to the next color gradient, and then repeat. So for example, it would look like: Red Gradient (30 seconds), Transition Red to Orange (10 seconds), Orange Gradient (30 seconds), Transition Orange to Green (10 seconds), etc.

I'm getting two types of error with this code that seem to alternate. Generally, the first error is this one that appears when the first timer (the 30 second one) goes off:

[image: The first error]

After dismissing that error message to see what would happen, this error pops up when the same timer goes off again:

[image: The second error]

At this point I think the source of error is in generating the colors properly in the function contained in `componentDidMount()`

Comment: please got through https://medium.com/react-native-training/react-native-animations-using-the-animated-api-ebe8e0669fae#.dwp3h9m0f and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32622466/animating-backgroundcolor-in-react-native . cheers:)

Comment: @Codesingh Thanks for the resources! After reading them I attempted applying it and, while it's progress, I an error when the app starts. I updated my question with the code I added and the error. Any idea on what changes I need to make?

Comment: did you find anything for this?

Comment: @Codesingh I updated the code in my question with what I found, but now I'm trying to figure out how to fix the error in the picture

Comment: You have alot of syntax error and confusion colorTop topColor

Comment: @Armin I have completed my solution. The animation is smooth now :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found a working solution!

Use linear interpolation to generate your gradient.
This is the simplest way I found to control the gradient properly.

**chroma.js** :

I found a library called [chroma.js](https://gka.github.io/chroma.js/) that can do this well ! They have a method called [scale.colors](https://gka.github.io/chroma.js/#scale-colors) that can do the job for you!

Install the package :

```
npm install chroma-js
```

You can adjust the `INTERVAL` and the `GRADIENT_COLOR_LENGTH` constants to change the effect.

Then use the generated spectrum variables in the code :

```
import React from 'react'
import { AppRegistry, StyleSheet, Dimensions, View } from 'react-native'

import TimerMixin from 'react-timer-mixin'
import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient'
import Chroma from 'chroma-js'

var screenWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width
var screenHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height

const TOP_COLORS = ['#EF2A2A', '#EF6A2A', '#1BD170', '#22D2E6', '#2A3BEF', '#EF2AD2', '#EF2AD2']
const BOTTOM_COLORS = ['#EF6A2A', '#EFD82A', '#61E822', '#26F084', '#2ADCEF', '#2A3BEF', '#EF2A2A']
const GRADIENT_COLOR_LENGTH = 700
const TOP_COLORS_SPECTRUM = Chroma.scale(TOP_COLORS).colors(GRADIENT_COLOR_LENGTH)
const BOTTOM_COLORS_SPECTRUM = Chroma.scale(BOTTOM_COLORS).colors(GRADIENT_COLOR_LENGTH)
const INTERVAL = 50

const GradientView = React.createClass({
  mixins: [TimerMixin],

  getInitialState () {
    return {
      topIndex: 0,
      bottomIndex: 0,
      colorTop: TOP_COLORS_SPECTRUM[0],
      colorBottom: BOTTOM_COLORS_SPECTRUM[0]
    }
  },

  componentDidMount () {
    this.setInterval(() => {
      let { topIndex, bottomIndex } = this.state

      topIndex++
      if (topIndex === TOP_COLORS_SPECTRUM.length) {
        topIndex = 0
      }

      bottomIndex++
      if (bottomIndex === BOTTOM_COLORS_SPECTRUM.length) {
        bottomIndex = 0
      }

      this.setState({
        topIndex: topIndex,
        bottomIndex: bottomIndex,
        colorTop: TOP_COLORS_SPECTRUM[topIndex],
        colorBottom: BOTTOM_COLORS_SPECTRUM[bottomIndex]
      })
    }, INTERVAL)
  },

  render () {
    return (
      <LinearGradient colors={[this.state.colorTop, this.state.colorBottom]}>
        <View style={styles.translucentContainer} />
      </LinearGradient>
    )
  }
})

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  translucentContainer: {
    width: screenWidth,
    height: screenHeight,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    opacity: 0.3
  }
})

export default GradientView
AppRegistry.registerComponent('GradientView', () => GradientView)
```

Comment: This is amazing, thank you so much! The animation is smooth and beautiful

Comment: No problem. Thanks for the interesting question.

Comment: This is awesome.  I have implemented this approach into an onScroll solution and it works like a charm.  Thanks!

Comment: Sir, you're a hero! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure that you followed the steps properly to add LinearGradient to your project : https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-linear-gradient#add-it-to-your-project

(Try rendering the component with no animation)

Second, fix your code.

You need to call `setState` each time to trigger a re-rendering.

The `<Animated.LinearGradient ...>`  element you have written is invalid. It doesn't exist. Change it to a `LinearGradient` element.

In componentDidMount, call `setInterval` and change the state of the animation inside the callback.

Here is a working example from the [documentation](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-linear-gradient#updating-the-values-for-fun):

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
} from 'react-native';
import TimerMixin from 'react-timer-mixin';
import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient';

function incrementColor(color, step) {
  const intColor = parseInt(color.substr(1), 16);
  const newIntColor = (intColor + step).toString(16);
  return `#${'0'.repeat(6 - newIntColor.length)}${newIntColor}`;
};

const AnimatedGradient = React.createClass({
  mixins: [TimerMixin],

  getInitialState() {
    return {
      count: 0,
      colorTop: '#000000',
      colorBottom: '#cccccc',
    }
  },

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setInterval(() => {
      this.setState({
        count: this.state.count + 1,
        colorTop: incrementColor(this.state.colorTop, 1),
        colorBottom: incrementColor(this.state.colorBottom, -1),
      });
    }, 20);
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <LinearGradient
          colors={[this.state.colorTop, this.state.colorBottom]}
          style={styles.gradient} />
        <Text style={{color: this.state.colorTop}}>{this.state.colorTop}</Text>
        <Text style={{color: this.state.colorBottom}}>{this.state.colorBottom}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
});

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  gradient: {
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
  },
});

export default AnimatedGradient;
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, AlexB. I updated my question with more information regarding your answer, please read it. The documentation example was actually the first thing I referred to when attempting to make this happen.

Comment: Have you tried using the exemple above without modifications ? Does it work ?

Comment: The setInterval function should be in the componentDidMount not the render function as you say in the update

Comment: I did a complete overhaul of the entire code and updated my question. First I made it exactly like the documentation, which works but doesn't suit my exact needs. After making modifications, I am left with the code that you see in my question.

Comment: My question helped you. Have you considered giving me a plus 1? Also, I'm working on a solution. I'm almost there.

Comment: Oh yeah, you have the plus one. You definitely deserve it, thanks for helping this far and I look forward to seeing your solution