# Animate text color change in React-Native

Tags: react-native

This problem has been bugging me for a while now and I am stuck.
I want to animate the color property of my text when a user clicks on a Touchable.

For this I am using an  tag.

What am I missing to make this work?

This is my component so far:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Text, View, TouchableWithoutFeedback, LayoutAnimation, Animated } from 'react-native';

import { CardSection } from './common';
import * as actions from '../actions';

class ListItem extends Component {
  state = {
    colorAnim: new Animated.Text('#000')
  };

  componentWillUpdate() {
    LayoutAnimation.easeInEaseOut();

    Animated.timing(
      this.state.colorAnim,
      {
        toValue: '#47bed1',
        duration: 5000,
      }
    ).start();
  }

  renderDescription () {
    const { library, expanded } = this.props;

    if (expanded) {
      return (
        <CardSection>
          <Text style={styles.textStyle}>
            { library.description }
          </Text>
        </CardSection>
      );
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { titleStyle } = styles;
    const { id, title } = this.props.library;

    return (
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback
        onPress={() => this.props.selectLibrary(id)}
      >
        <View>
          <CardSection>
            <Animated.Text
              style={{
                ...titleStyle,
                color: this.state.colorAnim
              }}
            >
              { title }
            </Animated.Text>
          </CardSection>
          { this.renderDescription() }
        </View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    );
  }
}

const styles = {
  titleStyle: {
    fontSize: 18,
    paddingLeft: 15
  },

  textStyle: {
    paddingLeft: 18,
    paddingRight: 5
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  const expanded = state.selectedLibraryId === ownProps.library.id;

  return {
    expanded: expanded
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(ListItem);
```

Comment: I think you need to use react-native Interpolate to make this work

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is the thread for `backgroundColor` prop animation, which is almost the same:
[Animating backgroundColor in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32622466/animating-backgroundcolor-in-react-native)

Basically, you can not use the color hex string directly, but declare your `colorAnim` as `new Animated.Value(1)`. The value inside `()` should be integer such as `1`.

And in the begining of render, the integer value is "interpolated" to real color like this:

```js
var color = this.state.colorAnim.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: ['#858a91', '#ffffff']
});
```

Then this `color` object can be used for the `color` prop of your `Animated.Text`

```js
...
color: color,
...
```

Comment: This cannot be natively driven with `useNativeDriver`. Is there an alternative?

Comment: Two options here, that I see: 
1. Put two text components (showing the same text) above each other (using absolute layout). You can then useNativeDriver and change the opacity of each text component.
2. Use react native reanimated v2 to change the color and archive native performance.