# List of different translations for Animated

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am learning Animated. In the document, I saw `translateY` and `translateX` and I learned them. I read the whole document but didn't find any other translation. I was expecting things like translateColor and such stuff.

For instance:

```
style={{
    opacity: this.state.fadeAnim, // Binds directly
    transform: [{
      translateBackgroundcolor: this.state.fadeAnim.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 1],
        outputRange: ['rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)', 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 1)'] 
      }),
    }],
  }}
```

Buy the I already know that I need to do this to get the background changed:

```
 var interpolatedColorAnimation = this._animatedValue.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 100],
      outputRange: ['rgba(255,255,255, 1)', 'rgba(51,156,177, 1)']
    });

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
       <Animated.View 
              style={[styles.box, {backgroundColor: interpolatedColorAnimation}]}
          />
      </View>
    );
```

But I don't know what should be changed inside that `transform` and what should be passed as the style property.

Where can I find a list of them? Why aren't they in the [react native doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animations.html)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Animating backgroundColor in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32622466/animating-backgroundcolor-in-react-native)

Comment: @bennygenel no that's not the answer, i saw that before and as i said i used it to solve my issue, but here i'm asking something else, i'm asking when to use `transform` and when to pass it to the `style`, and also where i can find the list of all translate. please delete that, thanks

Comment: Transform is a CSS property for styling components. When to use and when to pass it to style is up to your design and implementation. More info about translate is [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp).

Comment: @bennygenel please send it as an answerr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/transforms.html

Looks as though animating colour is not supported by transform

Comment: just a question, where did you find that page of the document? if you look at the left side list none of them is highlighted so i wonder how should i find this by myself?

Comment: usually i just google `react-native ____` for whatever im looking for. Usually helps. If not i go digging through the node modules